# Find ID in String using match

Tags: javascript, jquery, match

I'm building a widget that will generate a graph for an element when it is double clicked on the page. Without remaking all widgets this is the only way for me to tackle the problem.

I want find the ID of a widget from the html of an element.

All widgets I want to work are inside a div element `panel_content_id_#`

I want to find the number found on the line of code

```
var io_id=32715;
```

How can I search the string for this pattern and get the number (32715).

```
$('div[id^="panel_content_id_"]').dblclick(function(e){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    var code = $(this).html();

    // Find ID
    var id = -1;
    var search = code.match("var io_id=");
    if(search > -1){


    }

    console.log($(this).html());

});
```

The line of code im looking for will look like so

```
 var io_id=xxxxx;
```

Where xxxxx = some random number I dont know

I want to find xxxxx

Comment: what you want to find?

Comment: The fourth line literally says `I want to find the number found on the line of code var io_id=32715;`

Comment: If you just want to find it inside the String, then use pattern like `theString.indexOf(substring)` where substring is the id in string.

Comment: But there is a possible problem - `var id = 123".indexOf("12")` also returns true. Then probably `theString.indexOf(substring+";")` could be the way to go

Comment: I dont know what the ID will be

Comment: oh - you know that there is a line starting with "var io_id=" and you want to get ID from it?

Comment: Yes, the ID will be unknown but `var io_id=` will before the ID

Comment: If so, then `if String.indexOf("var io_id")>-1 { id = String.split("=")[1].split(";")[0] }`. If not - sorry about my lack of understanding your question.

Comment: Well remember that the string im looking at is the entire html for the widget -> 300+ lines of code, splitting the string after the `=` wont do much because there will multiple `=` before that specific line of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split it in two parts - All the code before the `var io_id=` and the other part is after that. 
And then you know that the line ends with `;`, so from that second part you cut of the stuff that is before the semicolon. 
**CODE**

```
$('div[id^="panel_content_id_"]').dblclick(function(e){
    console.log($(this).attr('id'));
    var code = $(this).html();

    // Find ID
    var id = -1;
    if (code.indexOf("var io_id")>-1) {
        id = parseInt(code.split("var io_id=")[1].split(";")[0]);
    }

    if(search > -1){
        console.log("The code betrayed me");
    }

    console.log("The id is: " +id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this regex pattern:

```
\d+(?! var io_id=)
```

Used like this:

```js
$('div[id^="panel_content_id_"]').dblclick(function(e) {
  console.log($(this).attr('id'));
  var code = $(this).html();

  // Find ID
  var id = -1;
  var search = code.match("var io_id=");
  
  if (search) { // Edited
    // New code
    alert(code.match(/\d+(?! var io_id=)/gim));
  }

  console.log($(this).html());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="panel_content_id_32715">
  Div content
  <br><br>
  var io_id=32715;
</div>
```